# Unix AWK on multiple column with spaces inside

Tags: csv, unix, awk, cpu-word

I am trying to use AWK to output to a csv file. The original data is obtained through another function "ucat function1 col1 col2 col3". I am trying to output this data to a CSV using AWK.

output from "`ucat function1 name pets vehicle`":

```
name=John Doe pets=Has a dog,fish vehicle=Owns a truck,a van
name=Mary Moe pets=Has a cat vehicle=Owns a car, a jeep
```

My full command:

```
ucat function1 name pets vehicle | awk '{print $1","$2","$3}' > /tmp/test.csv
```

What i get:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
John    Has fish
Mary    Has Owns
```

My Expected Output:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
John Doe    Has a dog,fish  Owns a truck,a van
Mary Moe    Has a cat   Owns a car, a jeep
```

Comment: where from truck, dog,cat, jeep come ? which does not exist in input ?

Comment: it would be better if you have shown the original data fragment

Comment: edited the original output from ucat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have an input file `test.txt` with contents:

```
name=John Doe pets=Has a dog,fish vehicle=Owns a truck,a van
name=Mary Moe pets=Has a cat vehicle=Owns a car, a jeep
```

*to output this data to a CSV using AWK* - we'll apply the following ***awk*** approach:

```
cat input.txt | awk -F'=' -v OFS='\t' '{gsub(/ [^[:blank:]]*=/,"=&");print "\042"$2"\042","\042"$4"\042","\042"$6"\042"}' > /tmp/test.csv
```

Now, `test.csv` contains:

```
"John Doe"  "Has a dog, fish"   "Owns a truck,a van"
"Mary Moe"  "Has a cat" "Owns a car, a jeep"
```

---

`gsub(/ [^[:blank:]]*=/,"=&")` - adds  `=` symbol before each key(e.g. `pets=` replaced to `= pets=`) to get a suitable key/value pairs for further splitting

`-F'='` - field separator

`-v OFS='\t'` - set ouput field separator

`print "\042"$2"\042","\042"$4"\042","\042"$6"\042"` - prints each column value sequentially

Comment: it works!!! but you should add double quote to each field or else it will all jumbled up

Comment: @EdMorton, cool stuff. I've fixed all that. Feel free to upvote my beautiful answer(I know you wouldn't)

Comment: @EdMorton, ok, thanks. Don't mind on my fighting manner, I'm  struggling all my life ...

Comment: It's good to hear that you didn't become a victim of unemployment or drugs, but became an experienced software engineer(or software architect)

Comment: the new command will cause everything to jumbled up in the same column with additional double quotes for each field

"John Doe""Has a dog, fish""Owns a truck,a van"

Comment: somehow the fields will still be separated by the commas

Comment: @LingShiWu, you better show how exactly should look the ecpected output

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest without the double quote and with comma in each column as well |John Doe|Has a dog, fish|Owns a truck,a van|

| represents column

Somehow things will still get chipped off when it comes to comma

Comment: @LingShiWu, to set comma as a field separator replace this part `-v OFS='\t'` with `-v OFS=','`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSV output then you'll have to enclose your fields in double quotes since they can contain commas:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    out = ""
    while ( match($0,/\s*(\S+)=([^=]+)$/,a) ) {
        out = "\"" a[2] "\"" (out == "" ? "" : "," out)
        $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
"John Doe","Has a dog,fish","Owns a truck,a van"
"Mary Moe","Has a cat","Owns a car, a jeep"
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match. With other awks you'd use sub() and split() on the result of the match() instead.